# How do i solve this error : django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-tests

I'm writing unit tests for my wishlist button/view and I'm trying to check if my book ISBN and the userID is added to the wishlist after I press the button. I've tried it but it keeps giving me the error stated in the title.

Here's my code:

```
#tests.py
class wishlist_view_test(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        books.objects.create(ISBN = "976354890", bookName = "testingbook1", bookVersion = "1",bookAuthor = "Carlie Presley", bookPublisher = "TeamBananaMonkey1")
        retailer.objects.create(retailer= "Amazon", sellerID = 1)
        retailer_book.objects.create(condition = "new", reviews = "4.5", ID= 1, bookType = "hardcover", ISBN_id= "976354890", sellerID_id = 1, price = 177.98)

    def test_wishlist_button(self):
        user = User.objects.create_user(username='user1', password='djangolife')
        self.client.login(username='user1', password='djangolife')
        response1 = self.client.post(reverse('TextSearch:wishlist',args=("976354890",)))
        self.assertEqual(str(wishlist.objects.filter(userid_id= user.id),'<QuerySet [..........]>')
```

```
#html code
<form action="{% url 'TextSearch:wishlist' book.pk %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" value="{{book.pk}}" name="isbn">
    <input type="submit" value="Add to wishlist★">
```

```
#views.py
class wishlistView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'TextSearch/wishlist.html'
    model = wishlist
    def post(self, request, pk):
        isbn = self.request.POST.get('isbn')
        current_user = request.user
        book = wishlist(userid_id = current_user.id, ISBN_id = isbn)
        book.save()
        return render(request, 'TextSearch/wishlist.html')
```

```
#models.py
class wishlist (models.Model):
    userid = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    ISBN = models.ForeignKey(books, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

class books (models.Model):
    ISBN = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    bookName = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    bookVersion = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    bookAuthor = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    bookPublisher = models.CharField(max_length=255, default ='NULL')
```

I'm using Django's built-in user model.

*** traceback error ***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ytann\Desktop\textbooks-for-less-9-website-design\textbooks-for-less-9-website-design\TextSearch\tests.py", line 67, in test_wishlist_button
    response1 = self.client.post(reverse('TextSearch:wishlist',args=("976354890",)))
  File "C:\Users\ytann\Desktop\python\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 741, in post
    response = super().post(path, data=data, content_type=content_type, secure=secure, **extra)
  File "C:\Users\ytann\Desktop\python\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 404, in post
    return self.generic('POST', path, post_data, content_type,
  File "C:\Users\ytann\Desktop\python\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 470, in generic
    return self.request(**r)
  File "C:\Users\ytann\Desktop\python\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 709, in request
    self.check_exception(response)
  File "C:\Users\ytann\Desktop\python\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 571, in check_exception
    raise exc_value
  File "C:\Users\ytann\Desktop\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\ytann\Desktop\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ytann\Desktop\python\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ytann\Desktop\python\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ytann\Desktop\textbooks-for-less-9-website-design\textbooks-for-less-9-website-design\TextSearch\views.py", line 25, in post
    book.save()
  File "C:\Users\ytann\Desktop\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 753, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "C:\Users\ytann\Desktop\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 790, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Users\ytann\Desktop\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 895, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "C:\Users\ytann\Desktop\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 933, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "C:\Users\ytann\Desktop\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ytann\Desktop\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1249, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\Users\ytann\Desktop\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1397, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\ytann\Desktop\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\ytann\Desktop\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\ytann\Desktop\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\ytann\Desktop\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\ytann\Desktop\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\ytann\Desktop\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: User_wishlist.ISBN_id
```

** edit **
I feel like it's something wrong with doing self.client.post, but I can't seem to figure out what's the problem

Comment: Please attach your `models.py` and a detailed version of your traceback error to your question.

Comment: i added my models.py, but yes I'll add the detailed version of my traceback error.

Comment: add null=True in ISBN

Comment: @RaghavSharma  But the view function usually works fine, I was assuming there was an error somewhere in my test class that i can't find at all?

Comment: can you print the book before book.save()? i suspect your post returns null value

Answer (score 0):

in test.py use this:

```
response1 = self.client.post(reverse('TextSearch:wishlist',kwargs={'isbn': '976354890'}))
```

Instead of:

```
response1 = self.client.post(reverse('TextSearch:wishlist',args=("976354890",)))
```

Comment: hi, it still doesn't work when I do that, it doesn't recognize isbn. But when I use {'pk' : '976354890'} it runs but gives me the same error as I did before.

Comment: you probably used pk in url.py, so you should get pk from request.POST in view.py. that's mean do like this: `isbn = self.request.POST.get('pk')`

Comment: if it was correct use this in template: `<input type="hidden" value="{{book.pk}}" name="pk">`

Comment: yea i changed it to what u stated, still doesn't work :(

Comment: use this `response1 = self.client.post(reverse('TextSearch:wishlist'), {'isbn': '976354890'})`

Comment: what is pk in post method of wishlistView? if it is book pk use it instead of `self.request.POST.get('isbn')`

Comment: nevermind i found a tiny mistake, i fixed the error. Thank you!